# Solver add-in error, solver32.dll not found and unexpected error occured

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am using excel 2016. I am trying to automate solver to optimize my portfolio. The code works on a few pcs, but it does not work on mine and a number of my colleagues. the error, solver32.dll not found and sometimes I get an unexpected error has occurred or available memory was exhausted.

I went through a lot of possible solutions:
 1. disable solver and restart excel and load it again
 2. change security settings for activex to prompt me
 3. re-install/repair office
 4. add constraints cell by cell
and many many more things.

The one thing that helped was to install 64bit office.

Now solver works manually. 
When using the VBA code it gets stuck on the solverAdd function. Any ideas?

```
    SolverReset
    SolverOK setCell:=Range("T28"), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range("weights"), Engine:=1
    'adding lower constraints
    For i = 1 To 8
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("S15").Offset(i, 0), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=Range("S15").Offset(i, -2).Value
    Next i
    'adding upper constraints
    For i = 1 To 8
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("S15").Offset(i, 0), Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("S15").Offset(i, -1).Value
    Next i
    'portfolio must add to 100%
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("Total"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=1

    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if solver add-in is enabled. Go to File tab > Options > Manage Excel Add-ins (Go button at the bottom of the window) and check if the Solver is enabled. If it is then try to uncheck all options and restart the excel, then do the same thing and enable the Solver again.

Was the file originally made in excel 2010? If so it might be a problem of incompatibility. Some people apparently tried to copy & paste the sheet to a new excel 2016 sheet and the problem was solved.

It can also be a COM Add-in related problem. Go to the Developer tab and try to uncheck all the options in COM Add-ins.

Comment: It is not any of the above. I had already tried your 1st suggestion. The code was created in excel 2016

Answer (score 1):

1. Install extension `File tab > Options > Manage Excel Add-ins > GO > Select the Solver Add-in > OK`
2. Wait until it is got installed
3. **Restart Excel**. It is the critical step